# Cloud functions onWrite for dynamically generated refs

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Here is how data is structured in my realtime database:

[image]

I have a realtime database setup as shown in the image above. I would like to take all the children in products onWrite and add them to an allProducts ref which will be under uid. My document structure is like stocks > uid > category> products. Followed the documentation buts its not showing for ambiguous refs

Comment: What do you mean by "its not showing for ambiguous refs"?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I want it to read the products nested deep down in products. firebase will child.key which is different for all categories but i want all products under category read

Comment: If I understand correctly, you should listen at the level of the `products` node like `exports.foo = functions.database.ref('/stocks/jeff/{itemId}/products').onWrite((change, context) => {})`. See the doc for more details: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#specify_the_database_instance_and_path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

exports.foo = functions.database.ref('/stocks/jeff/{itemId}/products').onWrite((change, context) => {})